# React native jump to next page without clicking

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

So i am building an app where there will be a page just for a gif animation. I want so that after that gif animation is done, it will automatically go to the next page. How do i do that?

Am i supposed to use a timer, so that the gif page will only appear for 3 seconds and then it goes to the next page? Or what is the best way to approach this?

how i manage routing:

```
    render() {
        return (
          <Navigator
              renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
              navigator={this.props.navigator}
               />
        );
      }
      renderScene(route, navigator) {
        return (
           ...);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not clear from your question what navigation scheme you're using, but regardless, the process is trivially done if the length of the GIF is known.  If it's unknown, I suspect you're in for a lot more work, but otherwise simply:

```
const GIF_LENGTH = 5 * 1000; // 5 second gif
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => nav.push({ name: 'NextPage' }), GIF_LENGTH);
    }
    render() {
        return < gif display here >;
    }
}
```

Obviously replace `nav.push(...)` with the particulars of however you manage routing in your application.